# Эффект перетекания

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Подскажите, где можно скачать javascript, который сможет сделать эффект плавного перетекания с предыдущей страницы при входе на новую страницу.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, это называется `slide`, нативно реализовано во всяких мобильных фреймворках. В Вашем случае если страница еще не подгружена, то придется её загрузить с помощью ajax, добавить в какой-нибудь спрятанный вправо (если хотите выезда справа) `div`, а затем с помощью `jQuery.animate` вывести как нужно. В таком случае ваше приложение имеет некоторые требования к архитектуре - каждая страница должна находиться в div-контейнере, которыми Вы будете манипулировать.

Comment: мне нужно не совсем это, скорее что-то вроде этого

<meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="revealTrans(Duration=4.0,Transition=12)">

но вот в Firefox, например, метод revealTrans не работатет, у меня этот эффект пашет только в IE

Comment: Лично я бы не стал полагаться на механизм, который работает только в IE и сделал бы с помощью `jQuery` кроссбраузерно. И вероятнее всего взял бы еще `Backbone.js`.
К сожалению, я не знаю ответа на Ваш вопрос в уточненном ключе.

Comment: Честно говоря, для меня это - темный лес...